# Typescript type conversion using destructuring rest on deep object

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6, destructuring

```
// inital types
 interface Source {
  id: string;
  version: number; // discard
  masterVariant: MasterVariant;
}

interface MasterVariant {
  id: number; // discard
  sku?: string;
}


// desired "lighter" types
 interface Target {
  id: string;
  masterVariant: MasterVariantLight;
}

interface MasterVariantLight {
  sku?: string;
}
```

to remove version property we can use the following

```
export class Convert {
    public static toTarget(source: Source): Target {
      const { version, ...result } = source;  
      return result;
    }
  }
```

can you see a way to discard `masterVariant.id` using above transformation?

Answer (score 2):

```
export class Convert {
  public static toTarget(source: Source): Target {
    const { version, masterVariant: { id, ...rest }, ...result } = source;
    return { id: result.id, masterVariant: { ...rest } };
  }
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEEsDtwFwQwDahgTwA4FMDOAoKMMAnAMzgGMNQBlAewFdCLQBvHUCAEwC5QsZCoAcwDcbUADciWcDUg9IdALYAjIsNAhQHcFjJxCHMYrh8iANX3g4kGDwCyJgoQsDrMUQF8ceG0VJMHU2dLNxYxcG5QBRU1DTBtXX1DdiwAazoAfh4%20AUgRHC9vTQ5scEIMDlAAIgRwQQALJyrkdGwfJ39KABV9QQwYMPYI7P4hUXZjIJcrG3tHcxCbABk6xs9vfD9ySkCnabcVhoHWFPSs3lG89ZwMAA80GkIBsgQTLFAAYVlJJ8HQNDoylqZAucBg4BBMBoPUIfRgAAosPRGBgeLQGBQAJQ8GFwv7sMiyPgsCRSGSQAA0oEme0WthJESpADoWeViR5mazsHQEAMPKAALy8ZEUcbsUDlGAMSAMyJsnkwJmM6nzYKuWYkllMtl80AeMVeDxAA)

Answer (score 1):

While pure destructuring is *possible* here, I think it'd be clearer to use one more line to construct the required `masterVariant` format.

Having a class that never gets instantiated doesn't make much sense either - a plain function would be more suitable for the task (which is fine, unlike in Java).

```
const toTarget = (source: Source) => {
    const { masterVariant, ...origSource } = source;
    const newMasterVariant = { sku: masterVariant.sku };
    return { ...origSource, masterVariant: newMasterVariant };
};
```